# GeoJSON EPSG::3857 to normal format (example normal format for Mapbox studio)

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, epsg, mapbox-studio

I'm really a novice in the field of the Geographic Information Systems (not to say that I don't know anything about it), but I retrieve via a WFS service some GeoJSON data.

The problem is when I want to import these data into Mapbox dataset, I get an error saying `Input failed. Datasets don't support features outside longitude +/-180, latitude +/-90`. (which I thought was normal before I realized that there are several "standards" if I understood correctly). In Mapbox tilesets I  had the following message `old-style crs`. Looking at the json file I see: `crs:EPSG::3857`.

So my question is how to convert these GeoJSON data into a more "conventional" format, especially to be able to import them into Mapbox data.

PS here a sample of my json :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "id1",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [-178543.91187612, 5882448.58513225],
                        [-178577.52460631, 5882357.92829031],
                        [-178596.91742747, 5882324.55133574],
                        [-178626.66849743, 5882300.02122665],
                        [-178661.20199806, 5882290.4923541],
                        [-178543.91187612, 5882448.58513225]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {
            "limite": "50m *",
            "bbox": [-178661.20199806, 5882290.4923541, -178543.91187612, 5882448.58513225]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "id2",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [-347809.38958008, 6020388.58369802],
                        [-348032.50431796, 6020261.6016117],
                        [-347957.11952919, 6020410.60267021],
                        [-347921.2199014, 6020429.137701],
                        [-347881.08191941, 6020433.52972921],
                        [-347842.04256863, 6020423.19474383],
                        [-347809.38958008, 6020388.58369802]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {
            "limite": "50m *",
            "bbox": [-348032.50431796, 6020261.6016117, -347809.38958008, 6020433.52972921]
        }
    }],
    "totalFeatures": 65908,
    "numberMatched": 65908,
    "numberReturned": 5,
    "timeStamp": "2020-12-28T23:54:17.923Z",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"
        }
    },
    "bbox": [-350088.63932757, 5882290.4923541, -178543.91187612, 6021659.01574107]
}
```

Comment: why not just request the data in epsg:4326?

Comment: Because it is the only format that I can get. They do not offer the possibility to get it in another standard. After I didn't know about WFS services until now... Do all WFS services offer the possibility to choose the standard?

Comment: so your question is how do I specify the SRS of a WFS request?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know, if it is possible yes, but if it is not, the question is still how to convert a geojson epsg:3857. I'm looking for the website who provides the API